# How to run a pruned node?

Tags: full-node, bootnodes, state-trie-pruning

I want to run a pruned node. If this correct that I'll have to bootstrap a full node first, and completely, in order to become able to then prune it?

A full node size is around 900Gb - 1Tb, right? And what's an approximate size of a pruned node?